# Python - Making a reference to an objects attribute

Tags: python, oop

I am working on a project that attempts to represent an electronic circuit.  This problem doesn't deal with circuit theory, just with connections between objects.

The problem is I need to make a connection between two objects in two different ways.

I have a Component and a Node.  A component has two terminals (positive and negative), each of which connects to a node.  A node can have many different terminals connected to it.

So, I can have

`component1.positive = node1`

But if I wanted to also do

`node1.add_terminal( component1.positive )`

That would just give node1 a reference to itself.

I would like to be able to have Nodes contain a collection of which terminals of which components connect to it or reference it, without having to write

`node1.add_terminal( component1, "positive")`

or something similar.

So, is there a way to store "component1.positive", so that it can be followed back to a Component and the specific terminal of that component?  Or is there another way to represent this many-to-one and one-to-many relationship?

EDIT:

It's important that the Node object can tell which of the two terminals of the component it was connected to.

Comment: Is it an option to make node a dictionary or list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use properties. Consider this (updated):

```
class Terminal(object)
    def __init__(self, component, node = None):
        self.component = component
        self.node = node

    def connect(self, node):
        node.add_terminal(self)
        self.node = node

    def disconnect(self):
        self.node.remove_terminal(self)
        self.node = None       

class Component(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self._positive = Terminal(self)

    @property
    def positive(self):
        return self._positive

    @positive.setter
    def positive(self, node):
        self._positive.connect(node)

    @positive.deleter
    def positive(self):
        self._positive.disconnect()
```

Usage:

```
c = Component()
n = Node()

c.positive = n # at this point c.positive.connect(n) thus
               # n.add_terminal(c.positive) is called 
del c.positive # at this point positive is "disconnected" 
               # from the node and vise-versa.
# or disconnect explicitly
c.positive.disconnect()
```

Comment: That is basically my first stab at the problem.  The problem is, node doesn't know which terminal of the component it was connected to.  There should be only one node connected to a terminal, and with this code, there could be at least as many two nodes referencing the same component, not the components terminals.  However, I think calling the code for the node object in the setter is very clean.

Comment: @KevinWard, in this case perform a check in `Node.add_terminal(t)` whether the terminal is connected to the other node. I'll update the code in a minute.

Comment: I had taken a similar approach to that as well with a Terminal class but I couldn't quite think of how to link it all together cleanly.  Your pattern seems pretty robust.  The only thing bit of kludge I'll have to do is to check if the terminal referenced is the same as either the reference at `component.positive` or `component.negative`.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! And thank you for posting an interesting question :)

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't. There is no such thing as a reference to an object attribute, only references to objects. You'd indeed have to store an object an an identifier which denotes a storage location in that object (doesn't have to be a string which is an attribute name, could be a key for a dictionary which is a member, or an index into a list).

However, you don't necessarily need that information. It may make more sense to model these relations differently, and/or to not give the objects themselves that knowledge, but treat them as a graph and perform traversals over that graph. This gives you knowledge of the endpoints of each reference, without explicitly recording it.